# When media queries override other media queries

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I created a series of queries for a specific element in a landing page.

So for my HTML I have this:

```
<div class="hsContent">
   <article> here is my awesome content. boom! </article>
</div>
```

and this would be the initial style for the above DIV:

```
 .hsContent {
    max-width: 600px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 25%;
    right: 25%;
    top: 10%;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

So, I wrote a series of media queries to drill down to the smaller screen sizes, the smallest being 420px, at the time.

```
    @media only screen and (min-width: 320px){
     .hsContent {
        width: 300px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 10px;
        top: 24%;
        padding: 5px 30px 30px 30px;
      }
    }
```

This works fine when I test in Chrome with Dev Tools. But, after adding another media query for a 320px width and then checking with Dev Tools:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px){
   .hsContent{
       width:300px;
       top: 10%; !important;
       padding-left: 10px;
       padding-right: 10px;
    }
}
```

...that query gets crossed out as if it's been overridden (screen cap below)..and in this case it's being overridden by the previous 420px width query. (Note that even included the **!important** in an attempt to force the positioning.)

[Here's a screen capture of the media query viewed with dev tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArUh3.png) (also showing a previous query for 960px width being overridden - which makes sense, of course)

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px)
  .hsContent {
    width: 300px;
    top: 10%;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
  }
}
```

So, what have I done wrong and what can I do to resolve this?

Comment: First off, to use `!important` its done like this `top: 10% !important;` without the semi colen in the middle

Comment: also, both of your media queries are set at the same `width` what ever media query that is bellow the other will be the result.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are going for: https://jsfiddle.net/pyexm7us/1/

I re-arranged your media queries, added the `420px` to one of the queries and fixed the syntax errors:

**css**

```
.hsContent {
    max-width: 600px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 25%;
    right: 25%;
    top: 10%;
    z-index: 10;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 320px){
   .hsContent{
       width:300px;
       background-color: red;
       top: 10%;
       padding-left: 10px;
       padding-right: 10px;
    }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 420px){
     .hsContent {
        background-color: blue;  
        width: 300px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 10px;
        top: 24%;
        padding: 5px 30px 30px 30px;
      }
    }
```